# Does finite expectation imply finite essential supremum?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I have a real valued function $f$ with the property that 
$$\mathbb{E}\big[f(X)\big] = \int f(x)\ d\mathbb{P}(x) \leq c$$
for some $c > 0$.

Does this imply 
$$ \operatorname{ess sup } \|{f(X)}\|^2 \leq c^2$$ 
with the same constant $c$?

I know $\mathbb{E}\big[f(X)\big] < \infty$ is a weaker assumption than $f$ being bounded. In the latter case the essential supremum is bounded.

Comment: No, and the supremum can even be infinite, think about the function $1/\sqrt{x}$ on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r>c>0$ and let $B$ be a Borelset with $0<\mathbb P(X\in B)\leq\frac{c}{r}$

If $f(x)=r\cdot1_B(x)$  then $\mathbb Ef(X)=r\mathbb P(X\in B)\leq c$.

The essential supremum of $|f(X)|^2$ is $r^2>c^2$.